# App-minimize ionic cordova pluging not working in iONIC5 app

Tags: ionic-framework

Added AppMinimize in app.module.ts's provider section . Then used inside app.component.ts for minimizing app on hardware back button tap as below-

Getting below error at runtime when back is tapped- 'Cannot read property 'minimize' of undefined'

Comment: Found any solution?

Comment: Hi Jameel, Can you pls share solution .